# Cannot delete row from jTable

Tags: java, swing

This is the code I've used for the delete function but it doesn't seem to delete any row I select. I first search for the required record using a jTextField `searchTxt`and then delete the matching record. The matching or search works fine, its the delete that doesn't.

```
private void deleteSelectedRows(){
   try{
            if(searchCombo_User.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("User ID")){
                dlt = "DELETE from user where user_id = ?";
            }
            else if(searchCombo_User.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Username")){
                dlt = "DELETE from user where username = ?";
            }

            pst = conn.prepareStatement(dlt);
            pst.setString(1, searchTxt.getText());
            ((DefaultTableModel)userTable.getModel()).removeRow(userTable.getSelectedRow());
            pst.execute();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}

private void deleteBttnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
       if(!searchTxt.getText().isEmpty()){   
            deleteSelectedRows();
            Update_table();
       }
       else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please search for the record you wish to delete");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do you execute  fireTableRowsDeleted() in the table?

Comment: No. Should I execute that within the function or where I call the function?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. It does not make any difference, the main thing is that the table should be informed about the deleted row.